# Measurability of limit of sequence of measurable random variables

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $X_n$ be a sequence of random variables on a complete probability space, converging in $L^2-$norm to some $X$.
Suppose that $X_n$ is $B_n$ measurable, for some $B_n$ in $L^2$ and suppose that $B_n$ converges in the $L^2-$norm to some $B$.

Is there any way to guarantee that $X$ is $B-$measurable ?

Comment: Could you please clarify what $B_n$ is? It's a little unclear to me

Answer (score 1):

No. Let $X\sim N(0,1), B_n=\frac X n$ and $X_n=X$ for all $n$. Then $X_n$ is $B_n$ measurable, $X_n \to X$ in $L^{2}$, $B_n \to B=0$ in $L^{2}$. However $X$ is not $B$ measurable.